# contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

Tags: web3js, truffle, meteor

Why can't deployed contract be found?

My node:

```
admin.nodeInfo
{
  ...,
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      difficulty: 36521801351,
      genesis: "...",
      head: "...",
      network: 3
    }
  }
}
```

network 3 from `truffle networks`:

```
Network: development (id: 3)
  Migrations: 0xfa79df82dce04e1a894df648f4f20af5a59f42f8
  WhaleNetworkV2: 0x93e21793323f9d3053b6a2bd2ab4234948aec210
```

in compiled contracts json file:

```
"networks": {
    "3": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0x93e21793323f9d3053b6a2bd2ab4234948aec210"
    }
  }
```

The code from which this error comes from:

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}

console.log("provider", web3.currentProvider);

whaleNetworkV2 = contract(WhaleNetwork);
whaleNetworkV2.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

whaleRewardsV2 = contract(WhaleRewards);
whaleRewardsV2.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

let whaleNetworkContract;
let whaleRewardContract;

web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accounts) => {
    if (err != null) {
        console.log("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
        return;
    }

    if (accounts.length == 0) {
        console.log("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
        return;
    }

    whaleRewardsV2.deployed().then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("whaleRewardsV2", error);
    });
});
```

The above code outputs:

> provider HttpProvider {host: "http://localhost:8545", timeout: 0,
>   connected: false} contracts.js:38 whaleRewardsV2 Error: WhaleRewardsV2
>   has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
>       at modules.js?hash=d495843d4bdb24e9ee23d52d143d36f9c62487b7:14057
>       at meteor.js?hash=cbcc712d51de4298c275e8dcf25c66c29914f19a:1167
>       at

Happens on both server and client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `from` key in my truffle.js which then resulted in getting this message even though looking like they were correctly deployed.

Comment: "from: From address used during migrations. Defaults to the first available account provided by your Ethereum client." - was it really the core issue? http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration

Answer (score 3):

I found my problem was that the metamask was on the wrong network

Comment: Same as me. Good answer!

Comment: haha yeah pretty obvious one but i had the same issue time and time again too :) Also another common issue is, you see mismatching info when testing from two clients, this is due to the time it takes for blocks to mine so both clients can see the same data, that one was confusing initially too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case by local ports were blocked. I found out by trying to ping my local Ethereum server using:

```
ping 127.0.0.1:7545
ping: cannot resolve 127.0.0.1:7545: Unknown host
```

After changing the port to an approved local port it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I added a localhost to Metamask and made the port 7545. And it worked. Then I copied the keys from Ganache to create account and it added the Eth. Also increase your gas fees